# Prepared SQL Statement returning blank from Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the code, following (Explanation is afterwards):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$uname = $_POST['uname'];

if($uname!=""){
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dota_site_test');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo("connetion error: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
        exit();
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username=?");

    $stmt -> bind_param("s", $uname);

    $stmt -> execute();

    $stmt -> bind_result($unamecheck);

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
        echo "taken: ";
        echo "name is ".$unamecheck;

    }else{
        echo "free: ";
        echo "name is ".$unamecheck;
    }
    $stmt -> close();

    $mysqli -> close();

}


?>
```

I am not sure where the problem is, but when I am, at the bottom, trying to `echo "name is ". $unamecheck;`, It is just returning blank. The way this code works is that on every key press the query is run to see if a Username is already present in the database. I have checked my Ajax, and the `$uname = $_POST['uname'];` is working fine.

In addition, I have ran the query "`SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username=?`" within mysql itself, replacing the `?` with my username, and that worked fine.

Have I made a mistake with the prepared statement? I am not sure if this is the way it must be done, but I am trying to be careful with SQL injection.

The result of my testing just shows `free: name is` being echo'd regardless of input. No other error codes are present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call

```
$stmt -> fetch();
```

After

```
$stmt -> bind_result($unamecheck);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the prepare query, try to separete the =? from the column name, like this:

```
SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username = ?
```

If this not work, print mysql_error() to verify if there is a mysql error

Comment: Don't mistake mysqli_ with mysql_

Comment: is true, you need to use $ mysqli-> error if there is

Comment: @Ganz Thank you for the suggestion. Nope, same result. Just `free: name is` and blank. The error came up with nothing. 

I have echo'd `$uname` just before the query, and it says the result is "lodagema" (this is the username that is IN the database). So I don't see how it could not work. :S